# something strange in List

Tags: python

I have just got a strange result in following code.

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

for i in mylist:
    mylist.remove(i)

print (mylist)
```

It generated [2, 4, 6, 8, 10] somehow. I would use "clear()" if I want to remove all. But, I am just interested in what is going on. Have I done something wrong for system preferenece? thank you for your help.

Comment: Oops, thank you for letting me know this question is duplicate. I am going to check it.

Comment: Refer to the note in the [for loop documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#for) as pointed out in one of the answers of the duplicate

Answer (score -1):

Just for future reference, when using Python 2.7 [this is the explanation you are looking for](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement):

> There is a subtlety when the sequence is being modified by the loop
>   (this can only occur for mutable sequences, i.e. lists). An internal
>   counter is used to keep track of which item is used next, and this is
>   incremented on each iteration. When this counter has reached the
>   length of the sequence the loop terminates. This means that if the
>   suite deletes the current (or a previous) item from the sequence, the
>   next item will be skipped (since it gets the index of the current item
>   which has already been treated). Likewise, if the suite inserts an
>   item in the sequence before the current item, the current item will be
>   treated again the next time through the loop.

Comment: Thank you so much. I should have took more time to check reference.